# Second order perturbed equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I've been studying asymptotic behavior on Ordinary Differential Equations. While doing some excercises I found out one excercise which has had me thinking for a while, so I am asking humbly for your help.
The statement is the following:

Consider the second order differential equation 
\begin{equation}
y''+p(x)y=0
\end{equation}
and its perturbed equation
\begin{equation}
z''+(p(x)+q(x))z=0
\end{equation}
where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are continous functions on the interval $[x_0,\infty)$. Show that if all the solutions of the first equation given are bounded and $\int^\infty |q(x)|dx<\infty$, then all the solutions of the second equation given are bounded in $[x_0,\infty)$.

I really would appreciate some help :).

Comment: ...and $\int^\infty |q(x)|\,dx$?

Comment: Yes, what about $\int^\infty \vert q(x) \vert dx$?  Do you pehaps mean (something like) $\int_{x_0}^\infty \vert q(x) \vert dx < \infty$?

Comment: yes. Sorry, I loss that while writing the question.